# node-fetch send post body as form-data

Tags: node.js, post, postman, node-fetch

I am trying to send a POST request with body as `form-data` since this seems to be the only way that works.

I tried this in Postman too and sending `body` as `raw JSON` didn't work.

So I tried doing the same with `node-fetch` but seems like `body` is being sent as `JSON` and I'm getting the same error as before (when using `raw` from Postman).

```
try{
  const { streamId } = request.body;
  const headers = {        
    "Authorization": INO_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
    // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>"
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }      
  const url = `https://www.inoreader.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/${streamId}`;
  const body = {
      AppId: INO_APP_ID,
      AppKey: INO_APP_KEY
  }
  
  const resp = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    //   body: body,
      headers: headers
    });   
    
  const json = await resp.text();
  return response.send(json);
} catch(error) {
    next(error);
}
```

Only setting body as `form-data` works:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the form-data package as mentioned in [their doc](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#post-with-form-data-detect-multipart)
so your code will be

```
const FormData = require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();
form.append('AppId', INO_APP_ID);
form.append('AppKey', INO_APP_KEY);

const resp = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form
    });
```

Comment: This docs are from node-fetch version 2

Comment: yes, it is still valid for everyone who can't migrate for ESM. But with this solution i'm getting socket hang up error

Answer (score 4):

Usar:

```
const form = new URLSearchParams();
form.append('AppId', INO_APP_ID);
form.append('AppKey', INO_APP_KEY);
```

Comment: A good answer always includes some explanation to elaborate how it addresses the problem asked in question.

Comment: Why do you use URLSearchParams for form data creation?  As here(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) said,  URLSearchParams is defines utility methods to work with the query string of a URL. It's for working with search parameters not for form data. Please consider your answer.

Comment: @TemuujinDev it says in their docs (the link that is in the other answer) to use `URLSearchParams`, and it never says to use the `form-data` package so this should be the answer marked as correct for other people that have this question